How to Digitally Sign a PDF File in Swift?
I'm currently working on a project in Swift where I need to digitally sign a PDF file. I have the following resources available:
Private Key stored in the iOS Keychain with a tag.
Public Key also stored in the iOS Keychain with a tag.
A valid certificate stored as a PEM string.
I need to digitally sign a PDF file with the above keys and certificate, but I'm struggling to find a clear and straightforward example or guidance on how to achieve this in Swift.
Specifically, I’m looking for help with:
Creating the digital signature using the private key and certificate.
Embedding this signature into the PDF file.
Any considerations I should be aware of regarding the format of the signed PDF (e.g., CMS, PKCS7, etc.).
If anyone has experience with digitally signing PDFs in Swift, I would greatly appreciate your guidance or code examples.
Thank you in advance!

You should try PencilKit for digitally signing PDFs.

@TaimoorArif PencilKit allows the user to create and manipulate drawings, but it's not inherently designed for digital signatures in the cryptographic sense (where I use a private key to generate a signature that others can verify). Am I wrong?
